# Bootstrap form causing overflow

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

**Problem:** I am trying to build a signup form and for some reason if there are any form groups inside of it, there is a slight overflow on the right side of the screen.

**Already done:** 
I have used Chromium dev tools and discovered that if I delete every .form-group then the overflow disappears. I also searched stack-overflow and Google to no avail.

**Current Code:** 
Here is my form (All of bootstrap is also included from the cdn)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
                <form class="">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

And `.content` is:

```css
.content {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

**Expected results:** 
I'm sure you've guessed from the title but..
Expected: No overflow, and a happy life.
Actual: Mild overflow and plenty of sadness

Comment: as you didn't 'include' your bootstrap cdn links, I'd ask you to please edit the code to include the bootstrap 4 links (bootstrap 3 in there at the moment).

Comment: Did you try `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` yet?

Comment: Why did you put the bootstrap 3 cdn onto it?? Completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` in your `.content` css :

```
.content {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Demo below :

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
      <form class="">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use bootstrap's built-in `.container` class instead of your custom one (I even recommend this when using bootstrap, more infos [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers)) and you don't even need to apply the `overflow: hidden` hack :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
      <form class="">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it but do you happen to know what was causing the overflow?

Comment: It is probably due to bootstrap's css default margin and padding in regards to the general layout of the page.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way to solve your overflow issue.

Comment: Thank you! Up until now I didn't really know what to use the container class for.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets in the same trouble in 2023 (with Bootstrap 5.2, the behavior continues…), here’s how I solve it.

The issue is caused by bootstrap CSS class `form-control`, which has left and right padding of `.75rem` with a `width: 100%`. So part of input box goes beyond parent `<div>` on the right.

### Solution

Just add a `px-0` (or maybe `px-1`) class to your `<input>` tag.

```html
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control px-0"
    id="fieldId"
    aria-describedby="basicInfo"
  />
```

**NOTE:** You may not want to use `overflow-hidden`, which may clip some part of the `<input>` box based on your grid systems and create an unwanted situation.